# NGINX virtual hosts with seperate lua_package_path variables

Tags: nginx, configuration, lua, virtualhost, openresty

I'm trying to serve two (Openresty) Lua web applications as virtual hosts from NGINX which both require their own unique `lua_package_path`, but have a hard time getting the configuration right.

```
# Failing example.conf

http {
  lua_package_path = "/path/to/app/?.lua;;"

  server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org
  }
}

http {    
  lua_package_path = "/path/to/dev_app/?.lua;;"

  server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.example.org
  }
}
```

1. If you define the `http` twice (one for each host), you will receive this error: `[emerg] "http" directive is duplicate in example.conf`
2. If you define the `lua_package_path` inside the `server` block, you will receive this error: `[emerg] "lua_package_path" directive is not allowed here in example.conf`
3. If you define the `lua_package_path` twice in a `http` block (which does not make any sense anyway), you will receive this error: `[emerg] "lua_package_path" directive is duplicate in example.conf`

What is the best practise of serving multiple (Openresty) Lua applications with their own `lua_package_path`, being virtual hosts on the same IP and port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it removing the `lua_package_path` from the NGINX configuration (since the OpenResty bundle already takes care of loading packages) and pointing my `content_by_lua_file` to the absolute full path of my app: `/var/www/app/app.lua`

```
# example.conf

http {

  server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.org

    location / {
      content_by_lua_file '/var/www/app/app.lua';
    }
  }

  server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.example.org

    location / {
      content_by_lua_file '/var/www/app_dev/app.lua';
    }

  }
}
```

After that I included this at the top of my `app.lua` file:

```
-- app.lua

-- Get the current path of app.lua
local function script_path()
   local str = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
   return str:match("(.*/)")
end

-- Add the current path to the package path
package.path = script_path() .. '?.lua;' .. package.path

-- Load the config.lua package
local config = require("config")

-- Use the config
config.env()['redis']['host']

...
```

This allows me to read the `config.lua` from the same directory as my `app.lua`

```
-- config.lua

module('config', package.seeall)

function env()
  return {
    env="development",
    redis={
      host="127.0.0.1",
      port="6379"
    }
  }
end
```

Using this I can now use multiple virtual hosts with their own package paths.

@Vyacheslav Thank you for the pointer to `package.path = './mylib/?.lua;' .. package.path`! That was really helpful! Unfortunately it also kept using the NGINX conf root instead of my application root. Even with prepending the `.` for the path.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue several month ago.
I do not recommend no use debug and release projects in the same server. For instance, you launch the one nginx application for both (debug and release) key may lead to unexpectable behaviour.
But, nevertheless, you can setup:

1. `package.path = './mylib/?.lua;' .. package.path` inside lua-script.
2. You can setup your own `local DEBUG = false` state and manage inside the app.
3. Obviously, use the other machine for debug. Imo, the best solution.
4. Execute different `my.release.lua` or `my.debug.lua` file:

> ```
> http {
>           lua_package_path "./lua/?.lua;/etc/nginx/lua/?.lua;;";
>
>
>
>         server{
>             listen       80;
>             server_name  dev.example.org;
>               lua_code_cache off;
>
>
>         location / {
>                 default_type text/html;
>                 content_by_lua_file './lua/my.debug.lua';
>               }
>         }
>         server{
>             listen       80;
>             server_name  example.org
>
>         location / {
>                 default_type text/html;
>                 content_by_lua_file './lua/my.release.lua';
>               }
>           }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your pointers, really helpful! And I totally agree on separating production and development servers in a live environment. Although in this case I have 12 virtual hosts running on my laptop and I don't feel like running 12 separates virtual servers (or NGINX processes) for that.